# Client-Server application Java

Tags: java, sockets, http, http-headers, httprequest

I have written a Server Class, my client is my browser. When i enter `localhost:8082`in my browser, the hardcoded website `www.mmix.cs.hm.edu`is opened. So far so good.
A website normally has more than one page. My server is only able to retrieve the home page `www.mmix.cs.hm.edu/index.html`, regardless of if i click on the other links. I would like to be able to navigate to these other pages. Can anyone take a look at my code and give me a hint on how i can proceed?

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String fromClient = "www.mmix.cs.hm.edu";

    try(ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8082)){
        System.out.println("Server started, waiting for clients...");
        while(true){
            StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
            try(Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                    DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedReader fromBrowser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()))){
                    try(InputStream url = new URL("http://"+fromClient+"/index.html").openStream();
                            BufferedReader getUrl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url))){
                            for(String line = getUrl.readLine(); line != null; line = getUrl.readLine()){
                                htmlCode.append(line);
                            }
                            String str = htmlCode.toString();
                            toClient.writeBytes(str);
                                //toClient.write("\r\n");
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `Socket` instead of a `URL` to directly pass in the data from the client connection to the server. `new Socket("www.mmix.cs.hm.edu", 80)`. It would be alot easier and much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ObiWanKenobi- Changed your code to extract the URL part. Try the below code snippet. Please go thru the comments in the code snippet. Run and confirm if the string manipulation works. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String fromClient = "www.mmix.cs.hm.edu";

        try(ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8082)){
            System.out.println("Server started, waiting for clients...");
            while(true){
                StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();
                try(Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                        DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                        BufferedReader fromBrowser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()))){

                        String line1 = fromBrowser.readLine(); //Line 1 is of format: GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
                        String dynUrl = line1.substring(line1.indexOf(32)+1,line1.lastIndexOf(32)); //dynUrl is of format:/index.html
                        //Please note that the query string parameters not taken into account and the code may fail if the query string contains space character.
                        //Construct a new URL based on dynUrl
                        try(InputStream url = new URL("http://"+fromClient+dynUrl).openStream();
                                BufferedReader getUrl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url))){
                                for(String line = getUrl.readLine(); line != null; line = getUrl.readLine()){
                                    htmlCode.append(line);
                                }
                                String str = htmlCode.toString();
                                toClient.writeBytes(str);
                                    //toClient.write("\r\n");
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ver much, this worked for me. I have a question though; Why indexOf(32)+1, lastIndexOf(32)? How do you come to this?

Comment: @Obi_Wan_Kenobi254 `32` is actually the character ASCII code for a space `" "`. Java is converting `32` to a `space` upon compiling because `char` and `int` are convertable. IMO it would be better to write the code like `line1.indexOf(' ')+1,line1.lastIndexOf(' ')`